# How to Make this CSS Responsive?

Tags: css, mobile, stacked

On my landing page: http://bit.ly/Z7GPai (password: welcome)  I have two text columns: ".one-half first"  and .one-half.

How can I implement the clear:both; command properly, so that on mobile screens smaller than 750px, the "one-half first" column actually displays BELOW the "one-half" column?

In other words, on mobile displays, I want the "one-half" column to display, well, first, right below the video, followed by the "one-half first"  (ie. the column with the red headline) stacked underneath.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a media query.

More info on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: thanks. I'll check that out. Could you suggest the css arguments that would stack the "one-half first" column below the "one-half" column when using a meida inquiry? It's not my forte...thanks.

Comment: If the order of the div's in the source doesn't matter, you could put the `.one-half.first` div after the `.one-half` div, and use `.one-half { float: right }` instead of `float: left;`

Comment: thank you Eric, but no. the order is important, but basically, when viewed on mobile, the importance changes and I want the .one-half to be displayed Before ie. on top of the .one-half first. Is it possible? Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: If Flexible Boxes were more supported, you could easily use the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to reorder the div's, but without Flexbox, I'm not sure how to do it. Haven't looked at it too closely, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909222/position-a-div-to-appear-below-another-div